# Understanding the work of foldr and unfoldr

Tags: haskell

I have hard time understanding how these bits of code work.

"Map" function must apply the function to all elements in given list, and generate list consist of results of applying. So we are giving our function f and some list, then in lambda expression our list transforms into head "x" and tail "xs", we applying function "f" to x and append it to "xs". But what happens next? How and what exactly foldr takes for its second argument (which must be some starting value usually). And for what purpose empty list?
And function "rangeTo" : we are creating  lambda expression, where we are checking that we are over the end of range, end if we are than we are giving Nothing, or if we are not at end, we are giving pair where first number append to resulting list, and second number used as next value for "from". Is it all what happens in this function, or I'm missing something?

```
--custom map function through foldr
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
--function to create list with numbers from first argument till second and step "step"
rangeTo :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
rangeTo from to step =  unfoldr (\from -> if from >= to then Nothing else Just (from, from+step)) from
```

Comment: `foldr` means that instead of `(:)` of the list, you write `f`, and instead of `[]`, you write `z` (the initial accumulator value).

Comment: I saw this explanation of `foldr`, but I dont understand about `[ ]`. If `f` stands for `(4+)` and list, that we are passing to map is `[1,2,3]`, then:
1st iteration: list breaks down to x=1 and xs=[2,3], then we use f on x, getting 5 and prepend it list and getting the result [5,2,3]. Then, foldr takes 5 from this list and prepend it our empty list. And on the secind iteration x = 2, xs =[3], we repeating previous steps. Is it right?

Comment: `f` typically does not stand for `(4+)` since it takes as input an element, and the accumulator.

Comment: To answer your question directly, the purpose of the empty list here is to be the initial value of the accumulator. `foldr`, when fully applied, takes 3 arguments: a "fold function" `f` (which takes 2 argments), an initial value `z` (which here is the empty list), and the list you are folding. What it does is, starting from the end of the list and working backwards, apply `f` to the current list element and current accumulator, producing a new accumulator. So it goes over the list from right to left, updating the accumulator as it goes, and returns the final value. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I want to add (but ran out of characters in the first comment): if you know some other languages, you will likely know how `fold` works - it's a standard library function in many of them, albeit it's often called `reduce` rather than `fold`, and usually folds from the left rather than the right (like Haskell's `foldl`), but the principal is exactly the same. Javascript and Python certainly both  have such functions, and I'm sure some other common languages have it as well.

Comment: @RobinZigmond More or less. But why we are getting in result a list, but not a single value? Because in lambda expression we prepend the result of function f to list?

Comment: On another note: this is two completely different questions. You would be better off asking about `unfoldr` in a separate question.

Comment: see https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html#$vfoldr

Comment: @luckydemon a list *is* a single value - or at least can be treated as such, as it is here. The accumulator is what eventually (after repeated applications of the fold function) gives your overall value, so its type has to be the same as the type you're aiming for. If you're just summing a list of numbers, you want a number out, so you do `foldr (+) 0` - the initial value is `0`, the same type of thing as what you want at the end. In the example you're implementing `map` in terms of `foldr`, and since this must result in a list, you have to start with a list.

Answer (score 1):

To understand **How `foldr` operates on a list**. It is better to write down the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Linear_folds) of `foldr` as

```
foldr step z xs 
= x1 `step` foldr step z xs1                                -- where xs = x:xs1
= x1 `step` (x2 `step` foldr step z xs2)                    -- where xs = x1:x2:xs2
= x1 `step` (x2 `step` ... (xn `step` foldr step z [])...)  -- where xs = x1:x2...xn:[]
```

and

```
foldr step z [] = z
```

For your case:

```
foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

where

```
step = (\x xs -> f x : xs)
z = []
```

From the definition of `foldr`, the innermost expression

```
(xn `step` foldr step z [])
```

is evaluated first, that is

```
xn `step` foldr step z []
= step xn (foldr step z [])
= step xn z
= step xn []  -- z = []
= f xn : []   -- step = (\x xs -> f x : xs)
= [f xn]
```

what happens next? The evaluation going on as

```
x(n-1) `step` (xn `step` foldr step z [])
= step x(n-1) [f xn]
= f x(n-1) : [f xn]
= [f x(n-1), f xn]
```

untill:

```
x1 `step` (x2 ...
= step x1 [f x2, ..., f xn]
= [f x1, f x2, ... f xn]
```

Answer (score 0):

> So we are giving our function f and some list, then in lambda expression our list transforms into head "x" and tail "xs", we applying function "f" to x and append it to "xs".

This is not the case. Look closely at the implementation:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

There is an implied variable here, we can add it back in:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f ls = foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) [] ls
```

`map` takes two arguments, a function `f` and a list `ls`. It passes `ls` to `foldr` as the list to fold over, and it passes `[]` as the starting accumulator value. The lambda takes a list element `x` and an accumulator `xs` (initially `[]`), and returns a new accumulator `f x : xs`. It does not perform a `head` or `tail` anywhere; `x` and `xs` were never part of the same list.

Let's step through the evaluation to see how this function works:

```
map (1+) [2, 4, 8]

foldr (\x xs -> (1+) x : xs) [] [2, 4, 8] -- x = 8, xs = []
foldr (\x xs -> (1+) x : xs) [9] [2, 4]   -- x = 4, xs = [9]
foldr (\x xs -> (1+) x : xs) [5, 9] [2]   -- x = 2, xs = [5, 9]
foldr (\x xs -> (1+) x : xs) [3, 5, 9] [] --        xs = [3, 5, 9]

map (1+) [2, 4, 8] == [3, 5, 9]
```

The empty list accumulates values passed through `f`, starting from the right end of the input list.

---

> And function "rangeTo" : we are creating lambda expression, where we are checking that we are over the end of range, end if we are than we are giving Nothing, or if we are not at end, we are giving pair where first number append to resulting list, and second number used as next value for "from". Is it all what happens in this function, or I'm missing something?

Yes, that's exactly what's going on. The lambda takes an accumulator, and returns the next value to put in the list and a new accumulator, or `Nothing` if the list should end. The accumulator in this case is the current value in the list. The list should end if that value is past the end of the range. Otherwise it calculates the next accumulator by adding the step.

Again, we can step through the evaluation:

```
rangeTo 3 11 2 -- from = 3, to = 11, step = 2

Just (3, 5)    -- from = 3
Just (5, 7)    -- from = 3 + step = 5
Just (7, 9)    -- from = 5 + step = 7
Just (9, 11)   -- from = 7 + step = 9
Nothing        -- from = 9 + step = 11, 11 >= to

rangeTo 3 11 2 == [3, 5, 7, 9]
```